# Predicting smoothed returns

Tags: returns, prediction

Due to the extremly low ratio of signal to noise in financial data, predicting raw returns is very difficult.

If we smooth out the price time series, say by an EWMA, and then calculate returns on this smoothed timeseries, we can introduce higher autocorrelations. Then predicting these smoothed returns is a lot easier, even for a simple AR(p) model. Similarly, taking a return over a longer period (say rolling 5 days instead of 1 day) also introduces some autocorrelation not seen in 1 day returns.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong in predicting smoothed returns? Of course, the smoothed returns will never be the same as the raw returns, and many times will not even have the same sign. But if you are building a model to predict trends, is there an issue with using smoothed returns?

Comment: I'm not sure this ultimately leads to better predictive models, and it seems like a free lunch. (As a _reductio ad absurdium_, if 5 day rolling is better than 1, why not use rolling decade returns?) Moreover, any statistical tests you use are going to have to deal with the headache of autocorrelated returns.

Comment: Smoothed returns are artificially autocorrelated. And they aren't forward looking, so they can't really tell you when the trend is going to change.